# Obtain all keys of a Neo4j index

Tags: indexing, neo4j, lucene

I have a [Neo4j](http://neo4j.org/) database whose content is generated dynamically from a big dataset.

All “entry points” nodes are indexed on a [named index](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/1.6.2/indexing-create.html) (`IndexManager.forNodes(…)`). I can therefore look up a particular “entry point” node.

However, I would now like to enumerate all those specific nodes, but *I can't know on which key they were indexed*.

Is there any way to enumerate all keys of a Neo4j [Index](http://api.neo4j.org/1.6/org/neo4j/graphdb/index/Index.html)?

If not, what would be the best way to store those keys, a data type that is eminently non-graph-oriented?

---

**UPDATE** (thanks for asking details  :)  ): the list would be more than 2 million entries. The main use case would be to never update it after an initialization step, but other use cases might need it, so it has to be somewhat scalable.

Also, I would really prefer avoiding killing my current resilience abilities, so storing all keys at once, as opposed to adding them incrementally, would be a last-resort solution.

Comment: @MattLuongo I didn't have time to try the workarounds offered in the answers. But there was never a “clean” answer, no.

Comment: BTW, the project for which this question was for is [SemWiktionary](https://github.com/MattiSG/SemWiktionary). Just because I learned since this question that some people consider it good etiquette to have that detail in a question.

Answer (score 1):

I would either use a different data store to supplement Neo4j- I like Redis- or try @MattiasPersson's suggestion and store the the list on a node.

Comment: If I have to use an additional data store, I would probably go for a dumb textfile or some serialization, adding another full-fledged database library feels overkill. But thanks for the suggestion, I'll try and have a look at Redis, seen it coming back often lately.

Comment: If it's a list which also changes rarely I'd go for a text file and load it into memory and write it out on shutdown or periodically or something ugly like that :) Having a 2M String[] isn't that great I'd say. Have you tried storing/loading such an array as a String[] property even?

Comment: It should change extremely rarely. Main use case would be… never after init, actually. But I have to support the possibility for adds without terrible performance. No, I haven't tried it yet, I'm currently off. I'll have a try at it in around 10 days.

Answer (score 0):

Is it just one list of keys or is it a list per node? You could store such a list on a specific node, say the reference node.

Comment: It is one list of keys. More than 2 million keys, though. I don't see how I could store such a list on one node, considering node [properties](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/1.6.2/graphdb-neo4j-properties.html) allowed types are primitives + String… I mean, excluding something as dirty as adding an indexed property per entry.

Comment: @MattiSG node properties can store `String[]` arrays, which satisfy your need. For another approach see my pending answer.

Comment: @MattLuongo Oh you're right, I had forgotten that properties could also be primitive **arrays**  :-S  Do you have any idea of the performance impact of storing a 2M array as a property, though? I don't know how storage is handled, but such an array of strings would definitely benefit from some compression, and I doubt it would be implemented…

Comment: @MattiSG Good question- I doubt it would be great, but someone who better knows Neo internals should have an idea (Mattias?).

Comment: Yeah, not great to store in Neo4j I think. Does this list change often or rarely? If it's just a big static list it could be ok perhaps.

Comment: @MattiasPersson I added details to the question  :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a different storage which increases complexety you could try again with

1. lucene indices. normally lucene is able to handle this easily, especially now that the MatchAllDocsQuery is better. but one problem is that the neo4j guys are using a very old lucene version.
2. a special "reference" field in every node especially for this key-traversal case linking to the next node where you easily get ALL properties :)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get all Nodes, which were indexed in a particular index, you can just do:

```
IndexHits<Node> hits = IndexManager.forNodes(<INDEX_NAME>).query("*:*");
try{
    while(hits.hasNext()){
        Node n = hits.next();
        ...process the node...
    }
}finally{
    hits.close();
}
```

Comment: Nope. Actually, that was what I was doing. 2M is too big, you'll get `OutOfMemory` exceptions, and terrible performance.  — (sorry for the downvote, but it has to be clear for future readers this is not a solution)